# Estimating derivative involving the gamma function

Tags: inequality, gamma-function, digamma-function

Let
\begin{align}
    \lambda'(p)=-c\frac{1}{(p+2)^\frac{3}{2}}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{3p}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{3p}{4}\right)}\left(\frac{3}{2(p+2)}+\frac{3}{4}\left(\psi(\frac{3p}{4})-\psi(\frac{3p}{4}-\frac{1}{2}) \right) \right)
\end{align}
where $\psi$ is the digamma function.

By Gautschi's inequality
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{3p}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{3p}{4}\right)}>\left(\frac{3p}{4}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}
\end{equation}
It is stated that the fact that $\psi$ is increasing on $(0,\infty)$, it follows
\begin{equation*}
    |\lambda'(p)|\geq \frac{3c}{2}(p+2)^{-\frac{5}{2}}\left(\frac{3p}{4}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\gtrsim 1,
\end{equation*}
uniformly for $p\in \left(\frac{4}{3},4\right)$.

*I don't understand in the end how I use the fact that $\psi$ is increasing to lower bound $|\lambda'(p)|$*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a direct consequence of the increasing nature of $\psi(p)$

If $\psi(p)$ is increasing, then by definition, we must have

$$\psi(m)-\psi(n) \ge 0$$

If $m \ge n$

This will imply that

$$\frac{3}{4} \cdot [\psi(\frac{3p}{4})-\psi(\frac{3p}{4}-\frac{1}{2})] \ge 0$$

The rest follows directly as a consequence of this and Gautschi's inequality.

$$\lambda'(p ) \ge -c \cdot \frac{1}{(p+2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \cdot (\frac{3p}{4})^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cdot \frac{3}{p+2}$$